# Splash Screen API not showing icon on Android lollipop 5.0 and 5.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-splashscreen

I am using splash screen API , everything is working fine but it doesn't show icon on android 5.0 and 5.1.

**SplashScreen API Version**

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
```

**Theme.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".CarApplication"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash"
            android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>
```

**Android Version 11**

[image]

**Android Version 5.0**

[image]

Now all I need to do is show the icon on devices with android 5.0 as well.
I did everything in the documentation but it doesn't seems to work with android 5.0

Answer (score 4):

Just found out after hours digging on the lib code :))). There is a comment on `androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen` class:

> On API 21-22, The icon isn't displayed until the application starts, only the background is visible.

Known incompatibilities: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

Comment: what can we do for these versions if we want to display icon?